# Finding if value exists in list with LINQ and saving info into a dataset, possibly

Tags: linq

i am brand new to LINQ, i currently have a look that loops through all orgs that a user belongs to, to make sure they have permissions to do various operations on the form.

looks something like this:

```
//loop through all user orgs to see if what they selected, they have access to
foreach (OrgPermission userOrg in user.orgs)
            {
                //get the org permissions for the selected org
                if ((ddlOrg.SelectedValue == (userOrg.Org.orgCode + "-" + userOrg.Org.orgSubCode)))
                {
if (userOrg.type.Contains("3") || userOrg.type.Contains("00"))
                        {
/

/do something here.
}}}
```

i am trying to get rid of the loop. as if the user has lots of orgs it's taking a little while to run, and i'm trying to optimize application run time.

i tried the following:

```
  bool has = user.orgs.Any(cus => cus.Org.orgCode + "-" + cus.Org.orgSubCode == ddlOrg.SelectedValue);
```

as you can see, the ddlOrg dropdown value are in org-suborg format. but i'm always getting false.

i would also like to save the result, not in a bool, but possibly as a single user.ORG that it found, so that i can use that to then check permissions and other stuff.

am i on the right track here? could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically wouldn't get rid of the loop, but rather filter the items that are being looped:

```
var users = user.orgs.Where(userOrg => ddlOrg.SelectedValue == (userOrg.Org.orgCode + "-" + userOrg.Org.orgSubCode) && (userOrg.type.Contains("3") || userOrg.type.Contains("00")));

 foreach(OrgPermission userOrg in users)
 {
      // do your operation
 }
```

That being said, this is likely not going to be much faster, as the LINQ query is still effectively looping through your items, but it will potentially be simpler to maintain.

If you only need to look for a single `OrgPermission` (ie: the first), you could speed this up via:

```
var userOrg = user.orgs.FirstOrDefault(userOrg => ddlOrg.SelectedValue == (userOrg.Org.orgCode + "-" + userOrg.Org.orgSubCode) && (userOrg.type.Contains("3") || userOrg.type.Contains("00")));

// userOrg will be the OrgPermission if found, or null if not.
```

Comment: thank you! i think this is what i was looking for! but instead of var, i can make it type OrgPermission, right?

Comment: @MadamZuZu Yes - the var is going to be the same as `OrgPermission` (in the second case), or `IEnumerable<OrgPermission>` in the first.  `var` just lets the compiler put in the type for you.